# Hide minute value on X Axis

Tags: jquery, highcharts, axis-labels

I am using the [HighCharts library.](http://www.highcharts.com/)

However I am finding it difficult to hide the minute values from the Xaxis -

```
xAxis: {
                 type: 'datetime',
                 maxZoom: 3600 * 1000, //one hour
```

As I am setting a point on the chart by the hour I do not want the minutes values to be visible -

[image]

As the plots are down to the hour and not to the minute, is it possible to remove these from the chart (the ones highlighted below) and just show the hour values on the chart i.e. **16:00** and **17:00**?

Comment: Try..point interval option in x-axis `pointInterval: 60 * 60`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see that minutes only after zooming in, then solution will be to set [`minTickInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minTickInterval) to `3600` (1hour). So it won't create ticks below 1hour distance between them.

Comment: Ok that is exaclty what I need, however where do I plly it in the code? Baring in mind I still have references to  pointInterval: 3600 * 1000 in the series component.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use labels formatter to hide minute values

```
 xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',          
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                 return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%S', this.value);
            }
        }
    },
```

If you want minute values use :

```
 return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) to resolve the issue.